# mvn clean compile package is not including src/main/java files in the build

Tags: java, maven

I have generated jar files before with maven and never faced this strange issue which I am facing with my current project.

It's a spring project having following `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SAMPLE_AOP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SAMPLE_AOP</name>
    <description>Spring boot project using AspectJ library for adding behavior without modifying existing caps backend micro-services.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Full configuration to configure each friendly parameters -->
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And I am building using the following command:

```
mvn clean compile package
```

Which simply includes some other dependencies without the actual code under `src/main/java`.

Please ignore the jar-with-dependencies part of the pom.xml, I do not want the dependencies to be packaged in my jar. I am not sure what I am missing here, Could you please point out?

Also, I checked in the project's build path, I could see that src/main/java is recognized as source folder and I have also explicitly mentioned it in `<sourceDirectory/>` tag in pom.xml.

Maven output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:SAMPLE_AOP:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 71, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.example:SAMPLE_AOP >----------------------
[INFO] Building SAMPLE_AOP 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/user/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/SAMPLE_AOP/src/main/java/com.sample/AnnotationHelper.java: C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\src\main\java\com.sample\AnnotationHelper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/user/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/SAMPLE_AOP/src/main/java/com.sample/AnnotationHelper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (default) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.sample.Application.testing())' in Type 'com.sample.Application' (Application.java:13) advised by around advice from 'com.sample.aspect.LoggingAspect' (LoggingAspect.java:43)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.sample.Application.testString())' in Type 'com.sample.Application' (Application.java:20) advised by around advice from 'com.sample.aspect.LoggingAspect' (LoggingAspect.java:43)
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void com.sample.Application.testing())' in Type 'com.sample.Application' (Application.java:27) advised by around advice from 'com.sample.aspect.LoggingAspect' (LoggingAspect.java:43)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/user/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/SAMPLE_AOP/src/main/java/com.sample/AnnotationHelper.java: C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\src\main\java\com.sample\AnnotationHelper.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/user/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/SAMPLE_AOP/src/main/java/com.sample/AnnotationHelper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (default) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] No modifications found skipping aspectJ compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:test-compile (default) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[WARNING] No sources found skipping aspectJ compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE\SAMPLE_AOP\target\SAMPLE_AOP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ SAMPLE_AOP ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-05T21:48:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what does this build produce? However sourceDirectory is normally src/main/java and you switched it to src in your pom.xml. Also you use jar-with-dependencies and the spring boot repackage, both building an an uber jar. Not sure how they interact with each other when both are configured. And you have two spring-boot-maven-plugin in your pom.xml. So clean up your pom.xml and just remove the sourceDirectory config and probably it will work as expected.

Comment: The build produces a jar having some spring dependencies, and nothing under src/main/java, actually I tried without sourceDirectory as well, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Also remove maven-assembly-plugin and the first spring boot plugin (without repackage). And add the output of maven to the question. Only with more information and a clean pom people can help you.

Comment: Also I am not sure if you need the aspectj-maven-plugin. I think the spring-boot-starter-aop should take care of it. Also this will already add all needed dependencies for aop.

Comment: Edited the question with your suggestions

Comment: Maybe also add the content of the jar file (and .jar.original file) and your directory layout and classes. When possible you can add your project to github and add the link. From the output I am confused about /C:/Users/user/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.5.RELEASE/SAMPLE_AOP/src/main/java/com.sample/AnnotationHelper.java. Why is the com sample written with a dot packages are folders with "/" and only in the java class package with dot is used.